# Extra blank value when parsing file to array

Tags: php, text-parsing

**EDIT:** checking for !empty works - but I would still like to know why the while seems to be continuing on after the end of the file. Thanks!

I am trying to parse a file that looks like:

```
export NTPSERVER_1 NTPSERVER_2 NTPSERVER_3 PSLOGHOST LOGHOST RSSHHOST RHPORT
NTPSERVER_1=8.8.8.8
NTPSERVER_2=
NTPSERVER_3=
LOGHOST="8.8.8.8"
PSLOGHOST=""
RSSHHOST="8.8.8.8"
RHPORT=88888
```

It's working great, *except* there is an extra last value in the array with no key and a null value. I have tried adding a check for $line being null to no avail. And I have double checked that the file does not have any blank lines after the RHPORT line. 
I am getting a "Notice: Undefined offset: 1" message and last thing in the array is [""]=> NULL 
I don't understand why the while doesn't seem to be stopping at the end of the file.

```
$file = fopen("files/network.conf","r");
$i = 0;

while(! feof($file)) {

  $line = fgets($file);

  if ($i > 0 && !is_null($line)) { // skipping first line of file

    $array = explode('=',$line);
    $fileValues[$array[0]] = $array[1];

  }
  $i++;
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend you to use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)  function

```
$array = file('file path', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$final_array = [];//empty array declaration
foreach($array as $arr){ // iterate over array get from file() function
   $exploded_array = explode('=',$arr);
   $final_array[$exploded_array[0]] = $exploded_array[1];
}
print_r($final_array);
```

As you can see only one-line code needed and you will get desired array

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful function, however that's not the array I want

Comment: @SeeSamRun  you can now easily manipulate this array to your desired array.Please check my edited solution. I did that

Comment: @SeeSamRun  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_contents and regex to get the values.

```
// Uncomment line below
//$str =file_get_contents("files/network.conf");
$str = 'export NTPSERVER_1 NTPSERVER_2 NTPSERVER_3 PSLOGHOST LOGHOST RSSHHOST RHPORT
NTPSERVER_1=8.8.8.8
NTPSERVER_2=
NTPSERVER_3=
LOGHOST="8.8.8.8"
PSLOGHOST=""
RSSHHOST="8.8.8.8"
RHPORT=88888';

// Find lines with = and save them to $matches[1] and [2]
Preg_match_all("/(\w+)\=(.*)/", $str, $matches);

// Create array as you expect
Foreach($matches[1] as $key => $val){
    $res[$val] = str_replace('"','',$matches[2][$key]); // remove " if it exists.
}

Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/CO59t